# Wordpress Ajax returns 0 from PHP data but the ajax is working

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Everytime I click Submit the popup alert only ever gives me a value of 0, also the console never logs what I echo from the php function. The String "Monkey" below does appear in the html, but the data variable doesnt work. (note: I've omitted the full ajax URL from public display)

In my WP plugin I've put this code:

```
function register_bio_script(){
wp_register_script('bio-script',plugins_url('js/bio-script.js',__FILE__), false, '1.0.0', 'all');
}
add_action('init','register_bio_script');
function enqueue_bio_script(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bio-script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/bio-script.js' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_bio_script');
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ MyAjaxFunction', 'MyAjaxFunction' );


add_action( 'wp_ajax_ MyAjaxFunction', 'MyAjaxFunction' );

function MyAjaxFunction(){
 $GreetingAll = $_POST['GreetingAll'];

echo "peanut";


$results = "<h2>".$GreetingAll."</h2>";

die($results);}
```

and then i have the JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var GreetingAll = jQuery("#GreetingAll").val();
jQuery("#PleasePushMe").click(function(){ 
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '.../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',//the full url goes here
        data: {
            action: 'MyAjaxFunction',
            GreetingAll: GreetingAll
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
            jQuery("#test-div1").html('');
            jQuery("#test-div1").append("Monkey");
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
 });
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved! i had to use wp_localize_script() for frontend ajax. wp ajax only works for backend users unless the script is localized.
the actual coding is complex but all the answers are
in this tutorial http://www.benmarshall.me/wordpress-ajax-frontend-backend/